# How to get locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges accurate readings

Tags: iphone, objective-c, locationmanager

Hi I have a requirement where I need to update user's location to the server while app is running in the background. I have used the code below to test it in the car and have found few discrepancies in the lat and long that are reported when the - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation: is fired.The coordinates are way far of to where I actually am at that moment.

I know the didupdatelocation uses cell tower readings hence not very accurate.I was wondering if there is anyway I can start [locationManager startUpdatingLocation] when the - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:; and then get the readings which are much more accurate.

Please any help or directions would be great and highly appreciated.

```
#import "LocationsAppDelegate.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"


@implementation LocationsAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;

-(void)initLocationManager {
    if (locationManager == nil) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone; // whenever we move
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters; // 100 m
       // [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
        [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
    }
}

- (void)saveCurrentData:(NSString *)newData {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSMutableArray *savedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[defaults objectForKey:@"kLocationData"]];
    [savedData addObject:newData];
    [defaults setObject:savedData forKey:@"kLocationData"];
    [savedData release];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

    NSDate* eventDate = newLocation.timestamp;

    NSTimeInterval howRecent = [eventDate timeIntervalSinceNow];

    //check if the data is less than 15 sec ago
    if (abs(howRecent) > 15.0)
    {
        NSLog(@"old data latitude %+.6f, longitude %+.6f\n",
        newLocation.coordinate.latitude,newLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    }else{

        [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

        NSDateFormatter * formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
        NSString *locationData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f, %.6f, %@",newLocation.coordinate.latitude, newLocation.coordinate.longitude,[formatter stringFromDate:newLocation.timestamp]];

        [self saveCurrentData:locationData];

        [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; 
    }    

}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSString *errorData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[error localizedDescription]];
    NSLog(@"%@", errorData);
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    
    if (![CLLocationManager significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable]) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Sorry" message:@"Your device won't support the significant location change." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        return YES;
    }
    [self initLocationManager];
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [locationManager release];
    [navigationController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour of `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` is not affected by the `distanceFilter` or `desiredAccuracy` properties.

So if you want to retrieve more accurated results, call `startUpdatingLocation`, and by playing with the `distanceFilter` and `desiredAccuracy` properties (`kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`, `kCLLocationAccuracyBest`) are the most accurated, but consumes more power, so play with them.

I didn't understand exactly the behaviour of your code. Why you call `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges` instead of `startUpdatingLocation`, but you call it inside the delegate method?

Comment: Thanks Yorxxx for your reply.I want the app to run in the background and post data after the significant distance changes only.How can I run the app in the background and wake the app when a user has travelled a significant distance. Thanks again for your help.